# Scroll header panel inside scaffold

Tags: polymer

is there a way to use core-scroll-panel inside core-scaffold?

This doesn't work, core-menu won't be displayed at all.

```
<core-scaffold>
  <core-scroll-header-panel navigation flex>
    <core-menu>...</core-menu>
  </core-scroll-header-panel>
</core-scaffold>
```

I also tried edditing core-scaffold template element to use core-scroll-header-panel doesn't work either.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `content` attribute or `content` class on the `core-menu` to make it appear in the main content area of the `core-scroll-header-panel`:

https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-scroll-header-panel

Example: http://jsbin.com/neror/3/edit

This is a little confusing, because it's different from `core-header-panel`, which places any unassigned children into the main content area. This seems like it's probably a bug.

If you don't need the extra-fancy scrolling effects, you could use a plain `core-header-panel` in your navigation drawer.

Comment: I opened a bug to see if we could get these two elements to line up: https://github.com/Polymer/core-scroll-header-panel/issues/27